# Ogre Gazebo problem ROS Fuerte

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-fuerte, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm facing without success a problem when I launch a Gazebo world (anyone, also the simple empty world). I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS fuerte. The error is the following

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master.[ INFO] [1357319107.934683162]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://blackBeast:11345
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::FileNotFoundException'
what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): 'plugins.cfg' file not found! in ConfigFile::load at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-visualization-common-1.8.4/debian/ros-fuerte-visualization-common/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/OgreMain/src/OgreConfigFile.cpp (line 83)
Aborted (core dumped)

I thing it is OGRE. The real point is it says it wants to load a file named plugins.cfg but this file is not in my computer neither in another one where Gazebo runs well.

Any idea?
Thank you in advance,

Neostek

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51480/ogre-gazebo-problem-ros-fuerte/) by [Neostek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2231/neostek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2013-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The same problem appears if I run rviz, so it is not a Gazebo problem

---

Originally posted by [Neostek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2231/neostek/) with karma: 156 on 2013-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0